# Does it make sense to do vecterindex after stringindex on categorical features?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

Say I have bunch of categorical string columns in my dataframe. Then I do below transform:

---

1. StringIndex the columns
2. then I use VectorAssembler to assemble all the transformed columns into one vector feature column
3. do VectorIndexer on the new vector feature column.

Question: for step 3, does it make sense, or is it duplicated effort? I think step 1 already did the index.

Comment: according to the doc of spark ml about decision trees, there is a line describing difference between ml and mllib, here I quote `use of DataFrame metadata to distinguish continuous and categorical features`, I think that where step 3 comes to its importance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it makes sense if you're going to use Spark tree based algorithm (RandomForestClassifier or GBMClassifier) and you have high cardinality features.

E.g. for [criteo dataset](http://labs.criteo.com/2013/12/download-terabyte-click-logs/) StringIndexer would convert values in categorical column to integers in range 1 to 65000. It will save this in metadata as a NominalAttribute. Then in RFClassifier it would [extract this from metadata](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/RandomForestClassifier.scala#L120) as categorical features.

For tree based algorithms you have to specify `maxBins` [parameter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/treeParams.scala#L59) that

> Must be >= 2 and >= number of categories in any categorical feature.

Too high `maxBins` parameter would lead to slow performance. To solve this need to use `VectorIndexer` with `.setMaxCategories(64)` for example. This will treat as categorical variables only those that has <64 unique values.